# join query help needed

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables

student

```
id      name
1-123   XXX
1-124   YYY
```

zipcode

```
zip  city
123  dk
124  raj
125  bog
```

I need to display city name beside every student.  I have tried to use the following query in mysql

```
SELECT student.name as name, SUBSTR(student.id,3,3) as std_zip, zipcode.city
FROM student LEFT JOIN zipcode ON std_zip=zipcode.zip
```

but result return all rows of zipcode table but i need the output as

```
name std_zip city
XXX  123     dk
YYY  124     raj
```

Comment: I *highly* suggest storing the `zip` in its own field in `student`  Having it as part of the `id` field and needing to use `SUBSTR` is a bad practice.

Comment: Brilliant id numbering..

Comment: Do you want id to contain zip ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `SELECT` alias in the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses of the same query, you need to use the expression itself.

```
SELECT student.name as name, SUBSTR(student.id, 3, 3) as stud_zip, zipcode.city as city
FROM student
LEFT JOIN zipcode
ON SUBSTR(student.id, 3, 3) = zipcode.zip
```

To avoid doing the `SUBSTR` twice, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT student.name, student.zip, zipcode.city
FROM (SELECT name, SUBSTR(student.id, 3, 4) as zip
      FROM student) student
LEFT JOIN zipcode
ON student.zip = zipcode zip
```

In this case, the first version is likely to perform better. See the [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e6e/2)

Comment: when you want to avoid an two SUBSTR calls by an DERIVED table you really make things worse.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e6e/1 even with indexes two complete table scans are needed and the optimizer didn't find possible keys to use..

Comment: Indeed the first version is better the subquery / derived table could improve performance when you need to run aggregate functions or fetch an smaller selection that you want to join then it would make sense to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't JOIN using `std_zip` because it's not a real field.  You need to call `SUBSTR` again when you JOIN.

```
SELECT student.name AS name,
SUBSTR(student.id,3,3) AS std_zip, zipcode.city

FROM student

LEFT JOIN zipcode ON SUBSTR(student.id,3,3)=zipcode.zip
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0478/2

---

However, in MySQL, it's bad practice to have multiple values in one field.  You should really make `zip` its own field in the student table.  It should look something like this:

```
id   zip   name
1    123   XXX
2    124   YYY
```

Then your query would be much nicer looking:

```
SELECT student.name AS name, student.zip, zipcode.city

FROM student

LEFT JOIN zipcode ON student.zip=zipcode.zip
```

New demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8137b/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name, z.zipcode
FROM student AS s
LEFT JOIN zipcode AS z ON SUBSTRING(s.id, 3) = z.zip
```

because subtring is a function and the result is not a 'real' table field you cannot use it in the ON-clause. So using substring in the on-clause should do the trick.

Is there any specific reason why you wil have the zipcode in the ID? What happens with the 10th student in your table? What ID does he/she have?